# Kate's terminal won't show most executables (ls in bin shows less items)

Tags: kubuntu, kate

I installed a recent version of the text editor Kate, by KDE, and as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmGMK.png) it does not recognise gcc, nor does it recognise sudo or anything I try to run.

The previous version I used simply had an instance of Konsole that I could use as I wanted, while this one shows `[ org.kde.kate ~]$` in place of the username... What's with it?

**Edit:** I got rid of the `[ org.kde.kate ~]$` by running `bash`; I checked the PATH variable, and although it is different from the one I'm using it still contains `/usr/bin`. But by running `ls` in that folder from Kate's terminal, most executables are not shown (e.g. there's not `apt`, `apt-get`, `gcc`...)

Comment: Is this maybe a snap installation of Kate? Snaps are sandboxed, so they may have limited access to files outside your home directory.
When installing some program, make sure you install the .deb/apt version, not the snap version. Snap equals problems unless you exactly know what you're doing.

Comment: @raj I installed it from Flatpak, which was the only way I found to install the latest version... could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, I think so. The version of a program bundled with Kubuntu is tested and works. If you install another version [of that program], it may or may not work.

Comment: @mell_o_tron Here I see that they have an AppImage version: https://kate-editor.org/get-it/ . Try this. As far as I know, AppImages are not sandboxed.